# Same Component in both asp.net, asp.net MVC and Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic, components, com+

I have a big website/application coded in Classic ASP, ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC.
I have a menu on top with a lot of HTML CSS JS, and some conifiguration (visible or not ...)
and lot of dynamic links.

So the problem is when i have to update the menu i have to update 3 files, one Include in Classic ASP, one ASCX user control in asp.net and one Partial view in asp.NET MVC

I hate code duplication, so is it possible to use only one component ? 
I heared about Com but i have no idea where to start.

Thanks for help

Edit : I am thinking know to use a .net Object, that can generate a string containing all the html that i need and then put it in the views MVC and in the asp.net pages
But how to use it in Classic ASP?

Comment: Wow that's a hell of a mix of technologies. If you continue this way you won't get very far. Have you considered homogenizing a bit? I mean stop writing new code and think how you could upgrade all this legacy stuff. The more time passes the harder the upgrade becomes. Currently IMHO you are at the stage of complete rewrite if you still have Classic ASP - a technology that was deprecated more than 10 years ago.

Comment: Hi daryn, i know that but i am not who decide, i have to solutions deal with it or to quit.
Classic ASP is perhaps deprecated  but you still can do really good things with it, for example now i rewrited all old asp in an MVC way in this same classic asp (VBscript Objects as models, IIS Rewrite as controller, html views thats excpects a model) .

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you using a **webapi controller** to expose this functionality; the webapi controller would return `json` or `xml` menu structure to the client browser this in turn would be rendered using by injection of the json over into the browser DOM and styled using CSS.

Classic ASP and MVC ASP.NET would use the same javascript and css.

Answer (score 0):

Guess, you can make an action method in asp.net MVC to render the dynamic menu and do AJAX load from the javascript in every part of the site?

**UPDATE:**

You can make an HTTP GET request in classic ASP to the aforementioned ASP.NET MVC handler, and cache results if its not very dynamic. Anyway it should be pretty fast if its within the same server. I suppose, request will look like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1887522/1176284)

Comment: Good Idea but i need the menu to render immediately, beacause the menu are the links for others home pages, so for SEO it"s important to load with the page so google can see it

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working in a legacy application that is very much similar to your case, how bad the life is :(

**I'll go for `XML`/`XSLT` in your case.**

I'll create an XML file that contains all the menu details and use XSLT to generate HTML from XML. I can easily use the XML and XSLT in all the three technologies. So every time you need a change you have to change either the XML or XSLT file.

You can even create a simple .NET component that uses the XML/XSLT approach which could be easily used in ASP.NET Web Forms, ASP.NET MVC (in custom view engine?) and in classic asp as well (you have to register).