# Using asp classic how do i create a gamer page?

Tags: asp-classic

I am fairly new to ASP.  I prefer using ASP classic at the moment cause that makes sense to me right now.  What I need help with is, I want to create a personal web page where I can put my gamer tag info into and it gets info from the net (Sony and MS) and displays information about my game collection and my trophies / achievements.  Can someone suggest something or point me in the right direction?

I am a member of a website www.playfire.com which does exactly what I am looking for except it no longer works for my profile and the web devs are busy with other stuff to worry about getting this working again.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you prefer using a framework that has been dead for 15 years?

Comment: Because I am just getting into ASP and it is easy to learn.

Comment: Why are you just getting into a framework that has been dead for 15 years?  You should learn ASP.Net with Razor and MVC.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That is at least a starting point even if it isn't ASP classic.  Thanks.

Comment: @SLaks Many companies still use [tag:asp-classic] including mine. I've been using [tag:asp-classic] for 15+ years now and continue to use it and support clients still using it. So how long has it been dead again??

Comment: @Lankymart that's called legacy application... don't try to keep the dead alive, you will end up with monsters. My company too still uses asp-classic. But finally 2 years ago someone realized, how maintenance -intensive and error-prone that is, and we started to redevelop this legacy application from scratch with asp.net with razor, MVC and ext.net. It's just so extremely difficult to implement new features on today's standard with technology from the last millenium.

Comment: @user3017424 classic ASP does have things like Microsoft.XMLHTTP and ways to screenscrapte external websites, but they're not easy to work with and not very reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question too common.

> I want to create a personal web page where I can put my gamer tag
>   info into

Keep all info about your games in database.

> and it gets info from the net (Sony and MS)

I assume no reason to download this data each time. perhaps will be enought to download it once in a week. There are few samples on this web site how to download web page by using ASP and ActiveX.

After you download info, I suppose, you should parse it -- to collect only info you want to display and save it in your database.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand all that.  For me though, the best way is to learn from examples.  You said that there are some on this website, any ideas on what to search with or do you have a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885170/http-get-request-asp-im-lost -- How to download web page from ASP