# Why will some site not load via XMLHTTPREQUEST using server side script (ASP) but I can load with javascript?

Tags: asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to load the following test urls with Classic ASP through xmlhttprequest. But two of the sites will not load. I know the script works because I can run some sites, but some will not load. Any explanation?

I've loaded these sites with Javascript and they do load (code not included, but standard AJAX or plain JS script). So why would client-side script work and not server-side code (ASP)?

```
'rss_url = "https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/2019/06/opal-fossils-reveal-new-species-dinosaur-australia-fostoria" 'THiS URL DOES NOT LOAD
rss_url = "https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/ex-minneapolis-officer-who-killed-justine-damond-sentenced-12-5-n1013926" 'THIS URL DOES NOT LOAD
'rss_url = "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-saudi-arms/republican-democratic-senators-seek-to-block-trump-saudi-arms-sales-idUSKCN1T61PL" 'THIS URL LOADS

Dim objHTTP
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    Err.Clear ' shouldn't be needed; can't hurt
    ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
objHTTP.Open "GET", rss_url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
'objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "text/html"
 aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)
   On Error GoTo 0
    If 0 = aErr(0) Then
      On Error Resume Next
objHTTP.Send
aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)
      On Error GoTo 0
       Select Case True
         Case 0 <> aErr(0)
           response.write "send failed:" &  aErr(0) & aErr(1)
         Case 200 = objHTTP.status
           response.write rss_url & objHTTP.status & objHTTP.statusText
         Case Else
           response.write "further work needed:"
           response.write rss_url & objHTTP.status & objHTTP.statusText
       End Select
 Else
       response.write "open failed:" & aErr(0) & aErr(1)
    End If       

    'ON ERROR GOTO 0
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Response.Write "NO feed from ..."
    end if
    if objHTTP.Status = 200 Then sdata = BinaryToString(objHTTP.ResponseBody)
     response.write sdata & "<hr>"
Set objHTTP = Nothing

Function BinaryToString(byVal Binary)
    '--- Converts the binary content to text using ADODB Stream

    '--- Set the return value in case of error
    BinaryToString = ""

    '--- Creates ADODB Stream
    Dim BinaryStream
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    '--- Specify stream type.
    BinaryStream.Type = 1 '--- adTypeBinary

    '--- Open the stream And write text/string data To the object
    BinaryStream.Open
    BinaryStream.Write Binary

    '--- Change stream type to text
    BinaryStream.Position = 0
    BinaryStream.Type = 2 '--- adTypeText

    '--- Specify charset for the source text (unicode) data.
    BinaryStream.CharSet = "UTF-8"

    '--- Return converted text from the object
    BinaryToString = BinaryStream.ReadText
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [(from this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885170/http-get-request-asp-im-lost)

```vb
Function GetTextFromUrl(url)
  Dim oXMLHTTP
  Dim strStatusTest
  Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
  oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
  oXMLHTTP.Send
  If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    GetTextFromUrl = oXMLHTTP.responseText
  End If
End Function

Dim sResult : sResult = GetTextFromUrl("https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/ex-minneapolis-officer-who-killed-justine-damond-sentenced-12-5-n1013926")
Response.Write sResult
```

Works fine for me, grabs the page and displays it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as on another thread you're helping me. I receive the error message: "msxml3.dll error '80072f8f' A security error occurred". I've tried other versions of xml and all throw an error. I can access some other https sites with no problem, so I don't think it's a security issue. But I cannot figure out what the problem might be. I'm running Windows Server 2008. Any advice?

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but what happens if you try to open the nbcnews.com address using the browser on your server desktop?